# Why does the text go outside the div container?

Tags: html, css

In this example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 8px solid #333;
}

#boxGreen {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
}

#boxRed {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxRed">Text 2</div>
<div id="boxGreen"> Text 1</div>
```

> Why does the "text 1" go outside the "boxGreen"? How can I make the
> text inside the box?

Answer (score 0):

Add display: inline-block; inside your greenbox div like this:

```
#boxGreen {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 8px solid #333;
}

#boxGreen {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxRed {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxRed">Text 2</div>
<div id="boxGreen">Text 1</div>
```

You are missing **display: inline-block;** in your #boxGreen

When you make a position relative you have to add **display: inline-block;**

Comment: You don't always want to add `display: inline-block` when you use `position: relative`. This is a specific case.

Comment: You are right this is a **specific case**

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 8px solid #333;
}

#boxGreen {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxRed {
  background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxRed">Text 2</div>
<div id="boxGreen"> Text 1</div>
```

**Solution 1** Mark the elements as display: inline-block; [Learn More Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

**Solution 2** Wrap the elements in another container and mark it as display: flex; [Learn More Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Problem** Your green element wasn't actually aligned with the red element, haha. It just appeared that way, remove the float: left and you'll see the container is actually beneath it. :)

Answer (score 0):

`float` is weird. It can be a tricky thing to work with because you get strange cases like this. A floating element is basically ignored by block level elements, but not by inline elements. Because your green box is a block, and the text inside is inline, the text is pushed down.

If you remove the `float: left` from the red box, you will see the green box move down and be realigned with the text. This is because both block and inline elements are now being pushed down.

If you instead set the green box to `display: inline-block`, the green box will be pushed around by the floating red box because it is now partially inline (although it will not wrap to a new line like the text did because it is also a block).

As you can see, floating elements have some strange behavior, which is why I generally avoid them. Unless you need some inline elements to wrap around some other element, you can usually use a `flexbox` or `grid` to do what you need with fewer side effects.

CSS-Tricks has some great articles to help you understand [floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: but if the "Text 1" is an inline element, why not accommodate to boxRed? Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to wrap the div elements in a container. After, you can use display: flex; to set it in row.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
div#boxGreen,
div#boxRed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 8px solid #333;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#boxGreen {
  background-color: green;
}

#boxRed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="boxRed">Text 2</div>
  <div id="boxGreen"> Text 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

attributing the display to inline-block for your #boxGreen should work

```
#boxGreen {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  display:inline-block;
 }
```